# newSelectMultiple() and and isSetDynamic() in getConfig() method not work

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-community-connector

- When set varriable both newSelectMultiple() and and isSetDynamic() in getConfig() method so remaining varriable not be displayed
- When set varriable both newSelectMultiple() and and isSetDynamic() in getConfig() method so remaining varriable not be displayed
- My expected is set varriable both newSelectMultiple() and and isSetDynamic() work
- Steps to reproduce:
- Step1 : When i set varriable (var x) both newSelectMultiple() and and isSetDynamic() and other variable (var y)
- Step2: On the screen (var y) not be displayed

Code sample:

```
function getConfig(request) {
  console.log(request);
  var configParams = request.configParams;
  var config = cc.getConfig();
  var option1 = config.newOptionBuilder()
  .setLabel("option label")
  .setValue("option_value");

  var option2 = config.newOptionBuilder()
    .setLabel("second option label")
    .setValue("option_value_2");

  var info1 = config.newSelectMultiple()
    .setIsDynamic(true)
    .setId("api_endpoint")
    .setName("Data Type")
    .setHelpText("Select the data type you're interested in.")
    .setAllowOverride(true)
    .addOption(option1)
    .addOption(option2);
  var info1Selected = configParams && configParams.api_endpoint;
  if(info1Selected != "option_value,option_value_2"){
    config.setIsSteppedConfig(true);
  }
  if(info1Selected == "option_value,option_value_2"){
  var info2 = config.newTextInput()
  .setId("info1")
  .setName("Search")
  .setHelpText("for example, Coldplay")
  .setPlaceholder("Search for an artist for all songs.");  
  }
  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
  return config.build();
}
```

Image Code sample follow website[image]

Image Error[image]